# Finding the central manifold of a dynamical system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, taylor-expansion, dynamical-systems

Take the dynamical system: $$x' = 0.5(1-x)xy$$ $$y' = -y(1-x)^3-y^2(2x^2-1.5x+0.5)-2x(1-x)^4+x(1-x)^3.$$
I want to find the central manifold and deduce its dynamics (stable or unstable). The above system is already in the following required form: $$ x' = Ax + f(x,y)$$ $$y' = By + g(x,y)$$
where necessarily $A=0$ and $B=-1$. Given this, we can parameterise the centre manifold by: $$h(x) = ax^2+bx^3+cx^4 +O(x^5).$$ First, we compute $y' = \frac{dh}{dx}x'$ which is: $$ y' = a^2x^4 + O(x^5)$$ and we compare it with the $y'$ from the above dynamical system, which is: $$y' = -x+(5-a)x^2+(3a-b-9)x^3+(-\frac{a^2}{2}-3a+3b-c+7)x^4 + O(x^5).$$ Comparing coefficients between the two $y'$'s gives $a=5$, $b=6$ and $c=-27.5$. This means that the centre manifold should be parameterised by: $$h(x) = 5x^2+6x^3-27.5x^4 +O(x^5).$$

**Question**: **I do not believe the stated $h(x)$ to be the correct approximation to the manifold**. You can see the **correct** centre manifold in the figure of the phase plane for the system I have attached. If you plot $h(x)$ on something like Desmos, you can clearly see that it is not a good approximation. Can you spot an error in my working or have I not included something I should have? Thanks

[image: Phase plane]

Comment: What is the fixed-point around which you are trying to compute the center manifold? You probably have multiple ones? In the derivations above you are considering the fixed-point  $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes, I am considering $(0,0)$. This is something I was wondering as well. I didn't appear to implement the choice of fixed point in to my working anywhere.

Comment: Well, you have to find them first by solving the problem $x'=0$ and $y'=0$. Then you could plot your $h$ on the vector field?

Comment: what do you mean 'find them'?

Comment: you have to solve $(1-x)xy=0$ together with $-y(1-x)^3-y^2(2x^2-1.5x+0.5)-2x(1-x)^4+x(1-x)^3=0$. $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a solution and $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is another. Also, how did you get the expression $y'=a^2x^4+O(x^5)$?. Please number your equations with the `\tag{<number>}` command...

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I'm not sure how finding the equilibrium points will help me find the central manifold. The equililbrium points are: $(0,0),\,(1,0),\,(0.5,0)$ and $(0,-0.5)$

Comment: Also, you have to linearize the dynamics in the vicinity of every fixed-point and compute the eigenvalues of the linear flow to understand which type of manifold is expected...

Comment: It was found by computing $y' = \frac{dh}{dx}x' = \frac{dh}{dx}0.5(1-x)xy= \frac{dh}{dx}0.5(1-x)xh(x) $. I have just labelled the central manifold as $h$, we actually have $y = h(x)$. Therefore there are 2 different ways of computing $y'$, so you just compare coefficients from there.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why you'd do that. The source I'm using to understand the process is this: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/yanghong.huang/teaching/MATH4041/part4.pdf and I'm just repeating the steps described in here.

Comment: I have evaluated the linear system at $(0,0)$ and it returns eigenvalues of $\lambda_{1,2}= 0,-1$. The central manifold theorem states (I think) that there will be a central manifold through $(0,0)$ because there is at least one eigenvalue with zero real part.

Comment: @pluton If you think you can answer the question and find the right central manifold then I'd be highly appreciative!

Comment: I think the linear dynamics around $(0,0)$ is incorrect. By writing $x'=u(x,y)$ and $y'=v(x,y)$, can you compute $\partial u/\partial x$, $\partial u/\partial y$, $\partial v/\partial x$ and $\partial v/\partial y$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes. I have found the Jacobian $Df(x,y)$ and evaluated it at $(0,0)$. I found the eigenvalues stated as above.

Comment: yes, but the eigenvectors were wrong...

Comment: I found the eigenvectors as $v_1 = [-1, 1]^T$ and $v_2 = [0, 1]^T$. But I'm not sure why the eigenvectors are relevant here because in my original working I didn't actually calculate them. Anyway, see below, my working was wrong from the off due to not being in correct normal form.

Comment: because the centre manifold is tangent to $(1,-1)$ and you assumed it was tangent to $(0,1)$...

Comment: In what part did I make this assumption?

Comment: when you expanded $x'=f(x,y)$ and $y'=-y+g(x,y)$. Sorry, you assumed it was tangent to $(1,0)$.

Comment: Okay, So Are A and B supposed to be matrices here? That doesn’t make sense to me. Do you think you’d be able explain how to find them? Thanks

Comment: That's what D.Thomine showed: you should have had $x'=A_{11}x+A_{12}y+f(x,y)$ and $y'=A_{21}x+A_{22}y+g(x,y)$ and $A_{11}=A_{12}=0$ and $A_{22}=B=-1$. However, you missed $A_{21}=-1$. And the eigenvector of matrix $\mathbf A$ corresponding to the vanishing eigenvalue is $(1,-1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input in this discussion. Feel free to paste that last comment as an answer and I will happily give it the tick and a +1 ! :)

Comment: You can accept D. Thomine's answer which is exactly what's above but was stated before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linearized system is wrong. It should be

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} x' & = & 0x + 0y + f(x,y) \\
y' &=& -x-y+g(x,y) \end{array} \right.$$

where bith $f$ and $g$ are second order terms. In particular, the center manifold is tangent to $\{x+y=0\}$, i.e. to the vector $(1,-1)$, which is what you observe on the plot. The expression for $h$ has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out. So I will have to change my system in to one that is of normal form. How do you have to change $h$? do you make the changes before or after it is fully parameterised?

Comment: And why do $f$ and $g$ have to be second order? Can't they be of higher order?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the system

$$
\dot x = f(x,y)\\
\dot y = g(x,y)
$$

It has at the origin the jacobian

$$
J_{0,0}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues $(-1,0)$ so we have an one-dimensional manifold.

Making $y = h(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ and substituting into the $y$ dynamics we have

$$
h'(x)f(x,h(x))=g(x, h(x))
$$

and with $n = 2$ we obtain after grouping powers of $x$

$$
\cases{a_1+1=0\\ \frac{a_1^2}{2}-3 a_1+a_2-5=0}
$$

and after solving

$$
\left\{a_1= -1,a_2=\frac{3}{2}\right\}
$$

and the approximation to the manifold

$$
h(x) = -x+\frac{3 x^2}{2}
$$

The flow along the central manifold is given by

$$
\dot x = f(x,h(x)) = -\frac{3 x^4}{4}+\frac{5 x^3}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}
$$

which is unstable.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. But why is the classification 'unstable'? because from the right of the origin, the flow is moving towards the origin. If you plot your $f(x,h(x))$, it shows that the flow for $x>0$ is stable, where as the flow for $x<0$ is unstable, which is what you see in your plot. Am I correct?

Comment: Look at the sign for the term $\frac{5}{4}x^3$.